# Boot Failed - Windows Boot Manager IBM Server x3400 M3

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I recently purchased an old IBM System X3400 M3 server, however, after installing Windows, I get an error message saying `Boot Failed Windows Boot Manager` and have tried multiple solutions suggested online. I know the drive is healthy after running checks, and I have tried Windows Server 2019, Windows Server 2016, and Windows Server 2012 R2.

- I have tried running the following commands with no success:

  ```powershell
  BootRec /RebuildBCD
  BootRec /FixMBR
  BootRec /FixBoot

  BootSect /Nt60 SYS
  # or
  BootSect /Nt60 ALL
  ```
- I have installed Hiren's BootCD and have completely recreated the BCD and MBR, with no luck. I have tried using `DiskPart` to copy across the boot files from my bootable installer USB to the HDD, but still nothing.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you review the [man page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bootsect-command-line-options) for `BootSect`, as the commands you issued [`/NT60`] are not appropriate for any OS >Windows 8?